# Set In and Out time attendance swipe in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, select

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1huB.png)I have a SQL Server table with all user's swipe information, including Userid, swipe-date, Department Id. I need to set first swipe as in time, second swipe as out time, third swipe as In time, fourth swipe as out time and so on (within a day).

For first two swipes, one must be In Time and other must be Out time in a single row. Next two swipes as In Time and Out Time in next row.

How is it possible using SQL query? If only odd number of swipes set last out as null.

How is it possible?

Given Table

```
UserId      Date                         DeptId
1001        2016-11-20 09:50:46            2
1001        2016-11-20 11:10:26            2
1001        2016-11-20 12:10:10            2
1001        2016-11-20 16:10:30            2
1002        2016-11-20 10:00:00            5
1002        2016-11-20 14:00:00            5
1002        2016-11-20 14:30:00            5
```

Expected Output

```
UserId       InTime                 OutTime            DeptId

1001        2016-11-20 09:50:46   2016-11-20 11:10:26    2
1001        2016-11-20 12:10:10   2016-11-20 16:10:30    2
1002        2016-11-20 10:00:00   2016-11-20 14:00:00    5
1002        2016-11-20 14:30:00   NULL                   5
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is clear. But provide some sample data, table schema and Your expected result. Also provide the query which you have tried out for this.

Comment: What boundary are you using for first swipe in? 9am? 7am? 1am? Are there any night shift workers in this situation? These swipe things are tricky if it's possible to accidentally double swipe etc. The basis of your solution is `DENSE_RANK()` but it's only available from SQL 2008 on. Please tag the SQL Server version

Comment: I use SQL 2008. Boundary is 9.00 to 17.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be double swipe, accidental swipe and night shift swipe may cause so many problems in my above functionality,like Mr.Nick.McDermaid suggested. So i have to change the above functionality to some other way. So many thanks to  Nick.McDermaid and Viki888 for replying my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
select UserId, in_time, out_time, DeptId 
from(    
    select UserId, 
           swipetime in_time, 
           lead(swipetime) over(order by UserId) out_time, 
           DeptId, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by UserId order by UserId) row_num
    from table1) as cte    
where row_num % 2 != 0
```

Hope this should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will drop your records into numeric buckets 0 and 1. Then you use that to crosstab it out

```
SELECT 
UserId,Date,DeptId, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY DeptId, UserId ORDER BY Date) % 2 AS InOut
FROM Table1
ORDER DeptId, UserId, DeptId
```

Try that and confirm that in is 0 and out is 1 then I can help you crosstab it

Again I must mention that this kind of thing has all kinds of edge cases, i.e. double swipes, accidental swipes, swipes crossing midnight etc.